# Is there time to see some of Valletta during a six-hour layover between flights?

Tags: airport-transfer, malta

We have a layover of six hours at the international airport on Malta.

Since the distance between Valletta and the airport is pretty short, can we get into Valletta for a brief city trip using a bus or taxi?

The cost is not an issue.

How long should we allow to return to the airport and to go through security?

Comment: Traffic can be quite bad, but you'd certainly have time to wander round a bit. Equally, you could head to Mdina. All depends what you're into really

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you would have enough time to walk around a little bit. For the Taxi ride to Valletta i would calculate 30 minutes one way (i suggest to preorder an [eCab](http://ecabs.com.mt/), they will be waiting at the airport for you). If you have checked luggage, i think you should be back at the airport 2 hours before your flight, however with only hand luggage or if your luggage is checked through, 90 minutes should be sufficient. I never encountered long lines at the security check.

For Valletta itself, as a destination for the cab i suggest the Triton fountain. That's also where the Bus terminal is. You can then walk over to the Upper Barrakka gardens, where you have a nice view over the bay.